# Poles in this circuit

Tags: capacitor, bode-plot

Just a simple question, how many poles has this circuit and where are they located?. This circuit is  used to represent the process of charging capacitor 2 from a charged capacitor 1.

[image]

I have this 2 simple equations:

1) (V1-V2)/R=V1/sC1

2) (V1-V2)/R=V2/sC2

And then i don't know what to do cause you can simplify the "s" variable by trying to find the Gain as A=sC2/sC1

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write what i had. Of course the 2 simple equations:
1) (V1-V2)/R=V1/sC1
2) (V1-V2)/R=V2/sC2
And then i don't know what to do cause you can simplify the "s" variable by triying to find the Gain as A=sC2/sC1

Comment: Question edited with what i have so far

Comment: Laplace transform has been over 20 years ago for me, but if I recall correctly: If you simplify for "s", then there are no poles left. Although useful for some calculations, I think you want to keep them for this particular exercise (or anything to do with phase shift).

Answer (score 1):

Poles and zeros are properties of a transfer function. To determine a transfer function you need to specify an input signal and an output signal, and initial conditions must be zero. If C1 is charged at t=0, then initial conditions are not zero, hence a transfer funtion does not exist. You can, however, analyse the circuit using Laplace transforms.